# Writing byte array to txt-file and reading it back

Tags: java, string, encoding, arrays

I have a byte array, that I need to write to txt-file. After that I need to read that byte array from there and here appears a problem.  I read this [Convert Java string to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499924/convert-java-string-to-byte-array/5500020#5500020)
But it works only with positive numbers. 
Here what I have

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    byte [] a= new byte [2];
    a[0]=15;
    a[1]=-2;        
    String line = new  String(a, "UTF-8");      
    byte[] b = line.getBytes();
    System.out.println(b[0]);
    System.out.println(b[1]);
}
```

and result is

```
15
63
```

`toString()` doesn't work as well.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Not sure (yet) but one thing that stands out to me is your `println` is expecting an `int` as input, not a `byte`.  That may be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my small function that converts String like `[-3, 123, 89, 0, -34, 78, -45, -78]` to byte array. I didn't know how to use Base64 encoding. So I wrote my small function.
To get Above mentioned string we should do `String line = new String(Arrays.toString(name_of_array))`

```
public class StringToByteArray {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String line= "[-3, 123, 89, 0, -34, 78, -45, -78]";
    String some=line.substring(1, line.length()-1);     
    int element_counter=1;

    for(int i=0; i<some.length(); i++)
    {           
        if (some.substring(i, i+1).equals(","))
        {
            element_counter++;
        }       

    }
    int [] comas =new int[element_counter-1];
    byte [] a=new byte[element_counter];
    if (a.length==1)
    {
        a[0]= Byte.parseByte(some.substring(0));
    }       
    else 
    {
        int j=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < some.length(); i++) 
        {
            if (some.substring(i, i+1).equals(","))
            {
                comas[j]=i;
                j++;
            }
        }           
        for (int i=0; i<element_counter; i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                a[i]=Byte.parseByte(some.substring(0, comas[i]));
            }
            else if (i==element_counter-1)
            {
                a[i]=Byte.parseByte(some.substring(comas[comas.length-1]+2));
            }
            else
            {
                a[i]=Byte.parseByte(some.substring(comas[i-1]+2, comas[i]));
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println(a[0]);

}
}
```

Result `-3`

I Hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

For me, this preserves the negative value:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte[] a = new byte[2];
        a[0] = 15;
        a[1] = -2;
        String line = new String(a);
        byte[] b = line.getBytes();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
    }        
}
```

For me, this outputs:

```
[15, -2]
[15, -2]
windows-1250
```

Basically, you're using the wrong charset to preserve negative bytes.  [You can find more info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749064/how-to-find-default-charset-encoding-in-java) And actually, the flaw in what you're trying to do is put bytes into a String in the first place.  [As you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1536365/61624),

> ... If you start with a byte[] and it does not in fact contain text data, there is no "proper conversion". Strings are for text, byte[] is for binary data, and the only really sensible thing to do is to avoid converting between them unless you absolutely have to.
>
> If you really must use a String to hold binary data then the safest way is to use Base64 encoding.

If you don't actually need to store this in a String, you should write/read from an Input/Output stream to the file. There are plenty of SO answers showing you how to do this.